# How to assign Pages to User Roles in Membership and Roles by Custom Asp.net Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I am creating a web application and i have already created page for creating Roles. but i want that admin should decide in which roles which are the pages or modules that role is authenticated to. I am using built in Membership and Roles.

For Menus i am using Sitemap for security Trimming it is working fine. i just want to 
make that thing customizable.

I have the option to hard code in web.config but i want to make it customizable.

```
<location path="Upload.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Uploader"/>
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Is there any way that we can make this customizable ?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the open source Web based Web Site Administration tool from UDRI: http://udriwsat.codeplex.com/

I believe they've got rules like that already built in.